# Create an animated proportional symbol map

Tags: qgis, time-series, timemanager

1. I have a number of locations (point data)
2. Each location have an attribute of different values over time (different columns)
3. I want to make an animated map with proportional symbols showing how these values of the same location change over (i.e. the dots become bigger over time). The below examples are similar to what I want to achieve.

http://bl.ocks.org/lucguillemot/2657e547d5556cc0acbb

https://observablehq.com/@jashkenas/italy-coronavirus-daily-cases-map-covid-19

Unfortunately, I am not good at coding. Can I make an animated proportional symbol map via the existing plugin Time Manager in QGIS?

I can try to reconstruct the data of the same location to different rows instead of the column if that is needed.

Comment: There should be a way to create an animation by creating a frame (=one map) per time step and then generate an animated .gif or animated .png. I think there are several utilities doing that ... but maybe time manager is a better idea ...

Comment: any ideas which utilities? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].